# Verify MongoDB/Mogoose saved array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, assert

I am at a loss on how to use the `findOne` method after a MongoDB/Mongoose save operation.

```
    // itemrefSchema.js
    const itemrefSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        pubRef: [{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
          ref: 'pubRefs'
        }],
        itemSpec: [{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
          ref: 'pubRefs'
        }],
        munInspect: [{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
          ref: 'pubRefs'
        }]
      },
      { minimize: false }
    );
    const ItemRef = mongoose.model('itemRefs', itemrefSchema);
    module.exports = ItemRef;

// modelTest.js
it.only('find a record', (done) => {
        let reference = new ItemRef({
            pubRef: [{'publication': 'military pub 1'}, {'address': '../media/a001.pdf'}],
            itemSpec: [{'publication': 'item spec 1'}, {'address': '../media/a001spec.pdf'}],
            munInspect: [{'publication': 'mun inspection 1'}, {'address': '../media/a001inspec.pdf'}]
        });
        reference.save().then(() => {
            /*ItemRef.
                find().
                where('pubRef').equals('pulication').
                select('publication address').
                exec(() => {
                    console.log(callback);
                    done();
                });
            */
        //});

            ItemRef.findOne({'ItemRef': 'pubRef'})
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    //assert(result.publication === 'DD Form 626');
                    done();
                });

            //console.log(result);
            //done();
        });
    });
```

I know that the reference data is being saved if I uncomment my `console.log(result)` and comment out the `findOne` method. I get data back from Mongoose's promise that looks like:

```
{ _id: 5b1ef810e8609509bc81fa19,
  createdAt: 2018-06-11T22:30:40.216Z,
  updatedAt: 2018-06-11T22:30:40.216Z,
  __v: 0,
  munInspect:
   [ { publication: 'mun inspection 1' },
     { address: '../media/a001inspec.pdf' } ],
  itemSpec:
   [ { publication: 'item spec 1' },
     { address: '../media/a001spec.pdf' } ],
  pubRef:
   [ { publication: 'military pub 1' },
     { address: '../media/a001.pdf' } ] }
    √ find a record (150ms)
```

I am trying to construct that assert by picking any of `munInspect` and verifying that MongoDB saved the contents. When I execute the `findOne` method, I get a response of 'null'. Any suggestions would be helpful.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: your schema doesn't have field ItemRef in your model so you cant query in findOne, so your getting findOne Result as null

Comment: i have answered below, you can approve my answer if your liked my efforts and ready to resolve other issues

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar, I apologize for not getting back to you.  Yes, your suggestion set me on the right path.  My first blush at my project can be seen in the 'feature' branch of https://github.com/EnergeticPixels/Hades.  The way I have it set up currently, the test run fails sporatically and never in same place twice.  I believe I need to refactor my test set up. But I am on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try as below with save function

```
reference.save().then((saveresult) => {
    //or you can directly print result like below

    console.log(saveresult);
    ItemRef.findOne({ '_id': saveresult._id })
        .then((result) => {
            //Now you can check your desired result
            console.log(result);
            done();
        });
});
```